# How to send a message every X seconds from server while the request is processing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server

I'm trying to figure out how to send a message from server to a client side while the client is waiting a response.
Let me explain:

1. User sends an input to server.
2. Server uses the User input to send to another API. It takes some time.
3. While client is waiting and request is processing, every 20-30 seconds should show a message like "Processing request, please wait".

The message should come from the server.

What is the best way to get it?

I'm using React / Nextjs if you ask me.

My code is this:

```
export const getMessage = async (text: String) => {
    const headers = {
      accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `${process.env.API_KEY}`,
    };
    const data = {
      text: text
    };

    const statusResponse = await axios.post(
        HERE_URL_API,
        data,
        { headers },
    );

    const output = statusResponse.data;
    return output;
}
```

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const { text } = await request.json();
    const output = await getMessage(text)
    return NextResponse.json({ data: output });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ data: error });
}
```

How can I send a message to client side every 20 seconds while the request is processing and when the request is finished, finally send the ouput?
Maybe using sockets?

Comment: Create a websocket connection on load and send messages through that, or use server sent events if your server supports it